# How to recreate this mouseover effect from Blue Origin?

Tags: javascript, css

On https://www.blueorigin.com/ they have a mouseover effect on the front page with the "Astronaut Experience" and "tech..." boxes that are side by side each other underneath the video.

I am learning how to code websites right now, and working on making one right now with that similar style of effect. How would I be able to implement this? I have some basic javascript knowledge, html, css and using nodejs+express

Comment: it's a web page. all of the html/javascript/css for everything in that page is already downloaded into your browser... start digging around.

Answer (score 1):

CSS Transitions on `:hover` pseudo class that change the background style.

http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/hover.html